# How to forward one url to another using mod_rewrite rules

Tags: mod-rewrite

Im trying to forward this url, but its not working - here is my code:

```
RewriteRule ^https://www.wsjwine.com/discovery_offer.aspx?promo=2227006$ https://www.wsjwine.com/discovery_offer_lp2.aspx?promo=2227006 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`RewriteRule` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) you can only test the [URL path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax). For further tests you need to use additional [`RewriteCond` directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

Now if you want to rewrite every request of */discovery_offer.aspx* to */discovery_offer_lp2.aspx* regardless of how the query looks like, you can just use this (example for the .htaccess file in the root directory):

```
RewriteRule ^discovery_offer\.aspx$ discovery_offer_lp2.aspx [L]
```

If you don’t specify a query in the substitution, the originally requested query is automatically appended to the new one.

And if you just want to rewrite that specific URL, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.wsjwine.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =promo=2227006
RewriteRule ^discovery_offer\.aspx$ discovery_offer_lp2.aspx [L]
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect query strings like that. Use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`.